# SyntaxError: invalid syntax on commit

Tags: python, sqlite

```
import sqlite3
import numpy


conn = sqlite3.connect('lotto.db')

cur = conn.cursor()

def fun(a,b,c,d,e,f):
    list = [a, b, c ,d, e, f]
    print(list)
    return numpy.mean(list)


numbers = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM combinations6")
numbers.fetchall()

for row in numbers:

    cur.execute("UPDATE combinations6 WHERE id = ? SET average = ?", (row, fun(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5]))
    conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

having trouble getting this to iterate over each row getting syntax errors and when it does run it only calculates the average of the first row and inputs that to all the rows of the database

what am i doing wrong to get it to iterate over each row and calculate the average and input it into the database?

pretty new to python so thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Don't change the question to remove the problem. If you want to show your new version of the code, add it as an addition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't in Python, it's with your SQL syntax. The `WHERE` clause comes *after* `SET`:

```
cur.execute("UPDATE combinations6 SET average = ? WHERE id = ?", (fun(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5]), row)
```

Don't forget to swap the order of the substitution parameters to match this.

Also, you're using `row` as the parameter for `id = ?`, which isn't right. You can't put a whole list into a parameter, it has to be a specific element of the list, e.g. something like `row[6]`. I don't know the actual position of the ID column in your table, so I don't know what the correct index is.

You can also do the entire thing with a single query:

```
UPDATE combinations6
SET average = (col1 + col2 + col3 + col4 + col5 + col6)/5
```

Replace `col1`, etc. with the actual names of the columns you're computing the average of.

Comment: Replace the `row` parameter with the element of the list that contains the ID. Or just use the new query that I added to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
import sqlite3
import numpy


conn = sqlite3.connect('lotto.db')

cur = conn.cursor()

def fun(a,b,c,d,e,f):
    list = [a, b, c ,d, e, f]
    print(list)
    return numpy.mean(list)


numbers = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM combinations6")
num = numbers.fetchall()

for row in num:

    cur.execute("UPDATE combinations6 SET average = ? WHERE id = ?", (fun(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5]), row[7]))
    conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

strangely fixed with adding to the query and using a different pointer and the different query

```
num = numbers.fetchall()
```

Thanks for your help getting me there :)